# Fetching records from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, rdbms

I have three tables in database as given below. I have to get records from these three tables such that the RF_date should be between the startdate and end date that I would be supplying to the query and then page_id should be equal to pagetype that I will supply to the query and one last is that Assigned_To. so suppose I sent " 10/10/2003 12:00:00 AM" as start date and  10/10/2015 12:00:00 AM as end date and pagetype=1 then  probably I will get all three records from the table tblFrontUsers but for each this record I have multiple entires in second table i.e "tblPatient", so I need to get latest "Assigned_To" for each user. for eg: for 115,latest  there is "5"  and for 116, the latest is "1" and then this 5 and 1 have it's names stored in the last table i.e tblUsers.
I am trying with following query but I am finding difficult to get the desired results.
Please help.

```
    select tblFrontUsers .Name, tblFrontUsers .ID, tblFrontUsers.page_Id, tblPatient.Patient_ID , tblUsers.Name       
    tblPatient.Assigned_To   from tblFrontUsers left join tblPatient on tblPatient .ID=tblFrontUsers .ID  
left join tblUsers on tblUsers.Id = tblPatient .Assigned_To
    where tblFrontUsers .Rf_Date >= '12/17/2003 12:00:00 AM'
     and   tblFrontUsers .Rf_Date<='3/21/2014 12:00:00 AM' and tblFrontUsers.page_Id=1 
    and there can be search column with tblPatient.Assigned_To also. If it is present we need to get records only with this otherwise all. 




tblFrontUsers 

ID         Name           Rf_Date                         page_Id
115        Sandy          10/10/2013 12:00:00 AM            1
116        Javer          10/25/2013 12:00:00 AM            1
117        Felipe         10/22/2013 12:00:00 AM            1

tblPatient

Patient_ID      ID        Assigned_To
1               115         2
2               115         3
3               115         5
4               116         5
5               116         3
6               116         1

tblUsers
Id              Name       
1               Max
2               Sam
3               Harry
4               mary        
5               maria
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from tblFrontUsers Fo
left join (select max(Patient_ID) as Patient_ID,ID from tblPatient
            group by ID)P on P.ID=Fo.ID
inner join tblUsers U on U.Id=(select Assigned_To from tblPatient P1 where P1.Patient_ID=P.Patient_ID)
where (FO.Rf_Date between '12/17/2003 12:00:00 AM' and '3/21/2014 12:00:00 AM' 
and FO.page_Id=1)
order by Fo.[ID]
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb33c/1)**

**Update**

```
select *
from tblFrontUsers Fo
left join (select max(Patient_ID) as Patient_ID,ID from tblPatient
            group by ID)P on P.ID=Fo.ID
left join tblPatient P1 on P1.Patient_ID=P.Patient_ID
left join tblUsers U on U.Id=P1.Assigned_To
where (FO.Rf_Date between '12/17/2003 12:00:00 AM' and '3/21/2014 12:00:00 AM' 
and FO.page_Id=1)
--and p1.Assigned_To='2'
order by Fo.[ID]
```

Comment: but I still need the record for "117" in tblFrontUsers

Comment: And I have one more problem. If I have to select records according to "Where tblPatient.Assigned_To=2). Then how would I can do so?

Comment: Sir, please tell me that if I neglect left join tblUsers U on U.Id=P1.Assigned_To in your updated id, the records set is still same. so, why this is added by you. Please clear me.

Comment: and how you are able to solve such a difficult queries?

Comment: **`left join tblUsers U on U.Id=P1.Assigned_To`** It is added to get values from `**tblUsers**` and to search records according to **`Assigned_To`**.

Comment: One request Sir.Can you please give a tip to get better in Sql server query handling?and thank you for giving your precious time. You rock.